# Is there a way to style/design a programatical button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox-gl-js

I implemented a Mapbox map on my website. On top of the Mapview I would like to add a button on the lower part of the page/map. As I couldn't figure out how to lay the button on top of the map (an HTML-button would just be below the map) I solved the problem with a programatical button in JavaScript.

```
function setupMap(center){
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: center,
        zoom: 14
    });
    

const nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
map.addControl(nav);
var button = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
button.style = 'z-index:10;position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;';
button.textContent = 'Calculate Consumption';
```

Now I would like to design/change the style of the button. Is there a way to do that? And if not, is there a way to put a normal HTML button on top of the map?

Comment: You want to change the style of the button in what way . Do you want to add borders,  color, padding or wanted that user can change the style of button

Comment: Rounded corners, a white background and also bigger

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to change the style of the button, best way is by setting an id to getting ahold of the button using it

```
function setupMap(center){
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: center,
    zoom: 14
});


const nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
map.addControl(nav);
var button = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
button.style = 'z-index:10;position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;';
button.textContent = 'Calculate Consumption';
button.id = 'map-button';
```

then later do that

```
const mapButton = document.getElementById('map-button');
mapButton.classList.add('map-button--edited');
```

and add your styles in the class you added `map-button--edited` in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the style you said above than add this to your `button.style` :

```
border-radius: 5px;background-color: white; padding: 10px;font-size: 20px;
```

The changed code will be like this :

```
function setupMap(center){
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: center,
        zoom: 14
    });
    

const nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
map.addControl(nav);
var button = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
button.style = 'z-index:10;position:absolute;top:10px;right:10px;border-radius: 5px;background-color: white; padding: 10px;font-size: 20px;';
button.textContent = 'Calculate Consumption';
```

> The value of `border-radius` `padding` `font-size` can be changed according to need

Comment: No problem, happy to help . If you find any of the answer which solve your problem you can mark it as accepted .